# Откуда берется байт?

Tags: c

```
char digits[] = "0123456789";

printf("%d", sizeof(digits));
```

Печатает 11, а мне казалось, что должно быть - 10.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Строки в C устроены особым образом. Дело в том, что строка в C — это, по сути, простой массив. А массив — это последовательность (в нашем случае) байтов. В нём нигде не хранится длина. Соответственно, чтобы была возможность вычислить длину строки, в конец строки добавляется нулевой байт.

Таким образом можно узнать длину строки (так работает функция strlen) — надо пробежаться по массиву до тех пор, пока в нём не встретится нулевой байт *(нулевой байт и символ «0» — это не одно и то же!)*. Встретили нулевой байт — значит, строка закончилась.

---

Проверьте сами. В случае Вашего массива `digits[10] == 0`.

На всякий случай, ещё раз обращаю Ваше внимание на то, что `digits[0] == 48`. 48 — это [ASCII-код](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) символа «0».

Answer (score 7):

В языках C/С++ строки (в том числе константные) в конце содержат символ с кодом 0, как маркер конца строки. Поэтому `sizeof(digits)` на единицу больше количества символов.